# Solve $\frac{(x - 1)^3(x + 1)^8}{(x + 2)^4} > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Solve the inequality

$$\frac{(x - 1)^3(x + 1)^8}{(x + 2)^4} > 0$$

A) $X<1$

B) $X>1$

C) $X>-1$

D) $X<-1$

E) $X>-2$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Have you tried anything on this problem? Where are you having trouble? Please note that bare problem statements are frequently poorly received.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the comment. I'm having difficulty understanding what to do with the exponents in order to simplify the problem, since 3 is less than 4 and 8 is greater than 4 then would the problem end up looking like this at a certain point: (X-1)^-1(X+1)^4/X+2, and if so, what do I do next?

Comment: I've edited your post to format it and have a specific title; please check it's correct. What can you say about the sign of the denominator, and the sign of the $(x + 1)^8$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct thank you, do you subtract the two exponents 8 and 4?

Comment: No; the bases are different, so there's no way to combine the exponents.

Comment: Can you help me out by letting me know where I'm supposed to go with this?

Answer (score 1):

Since both factors $(x+1)^8$ and $(x+2)^4$ are sqares they are always non negative. The only factor that determines the sign is therefore $(x-1)^3$. Now since you want the inequalty to be positive, you are forced you to chose $x > 1$.

Comment: Ouch, my bad. I guess I focused on x > 1, for which the squares are positive, but you are completely right. I edited.